# Shifting one equation to the height of two others

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

Assume the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times X \times W + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} +  \mathbf{Z}, \ \ t \in \{2003;2017\} \\  i \in \{1;N\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I want to position the long equation so that it is in the middle of the other two, with respect to the height.

[image]

That means that the underlined equation should be moved downwards as it is shown by the dotted line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times X \times W + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} +  \mathbf{Z}, \ \
\begin{array}{l}
      t \in \{2003;2017\} \\
      i \in \{1;N\}
\end{array}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why use `aligned` here there is only one line and no alignment points specified?????

Comment: I've just copied the author's code, probably author had some requirements outside of MWE

Comment: never trust the authors:-)

Answer (score 4):

Your main equation should not be in the `aligned`, there is only one equation, and no alignment points, you just need a mult-line construct such as `aligned` for the side conditions:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times X \times W + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it} +  \mathbf{Z},
\quad
\begin{aligned}
&t \in \{2003;2017\} \\
&i \in \{1;N\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```